# Cant get ipython to run

Tags: python-2.7, jupyter-notebook

I installed ipynotebook using pip and get this error everytime i try to start ipython notebook using terminal (ubuntu 14.04)

```
siddharth@siddharth-HP-Pavilion-g6-Notebook-PC:~$ ipython notebook
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/usr/local/bin/ipython", line 7, in <module>

from IPython import start_ipython

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/__init__.py", line 47, in <module>

from .core.application import Application

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/core/application.py", line 22, in <module>

from traitlets.config.application import Application, catch_config_error

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/traitlets/config/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>

from .application import *

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 17, in <module>

from decorator import decorator

ImportError: No module named decorator
```

What should I do?

Comment: have you tried  `pip install decorator`?